# How to pass co-variant varargs through apply() to a function that takes co-variant varargs of the same type

Tags: scala

Pardon any mistaken terminology; I am relatively new to Scala. I will endeavor to clarify as necessary :)

I want to setup a function[T <: Closeable, R], with parameters T*, function (T*)=>R, then invoke the function with the T* varargs as it's arguments. This is probably much clearer in code:

```
import java.io.Closeable

object Loans {
    /**
     * works fine, yay! 
     * Eg: using(new FileWriter(file)) { fw => ...use fw... }
     */
    def using[T <: Closeable, R](c: T)(action: T => R): R = {
        try {
            action(c)
        } finally {
            if (null != c) c.close
        }
    }

    /**
     * Won't compile:
     *  type mismatch;  
     *  found: closeables.type (with underlying type T*)  
     *  required: T  possible cause: missing arguments for method or constructor    
     * 
     * Intended usage is:
     * 
     *  usingva(new FileWriter(f), new OtherCloseable()) { ... }
     */
    def usingva[T <: Closeable, R](closeables: T*)(action: (T*) => R): Unit = {
        try {
            action.apply(closeables)
        } finally {
            //...close everything...
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately the usingva version doesn't compile and I am at somewhat of a loss for how best to accomplish the varargs loan structure.

Any and all advice much appreciated, ty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to put a `:_*` behind the parameter to tell the compiler that this is not one single argument but the entire seq of arguments:

```
action(closeables :_*)
```

---

*Edit concerning your second question in the comment:* For your specific problem it might be a better choice not to use varargs but the resulting `Seq` directly in combination with a partial function:

```
def usingva[T <: Closeable, R](closeables: T*)(action: PartialFunction[Seq[T], R]): Unit = {
  try {            
    action(closeables) 
  } 
  finally {
    //...close everything... 
  } 
}
```

this can then be used like this:

```
usingva(new FileWriter(file), new FileWriter(file) {
   case Seq(fw1,fw2) => ... // You can use fw1 and fw2 seperately here
}
```

There is unfortunately no way to make this typesafe (ie. check that number of parameters match the function at compile time) except for creating `using` functions for all numbers of parameters because there is no integer support on type level in scala. Same problem like tuples... that is why there are actually classes `Tuple1`, `Tuple2`, ... , `Tuple22` (Yes... they stop at 22)

Comment: OK; action(closeables: _*) and action.apply(closeables: _*) both compile. This may be a dumb question but is there a way to get the individual items into variables? That is, this works: `usingva(new FileWriter(file), new FileWriter(file)) { fw => ... }` but I'd prefer to be able to do something along the lines of `usingva(new FileWriter(file), new FileWriter(file)) { fw1, fw2 => ... }`. That is, to get each closeable in its own variable instead of getting one with FileWriter*?

Comment: ty for the update; realistically creating 2 or 3 `using` functions is probably just fine but knowing how to write the general purpose one (to which the using 1/2/3/... functions likely delegate) is most helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the varargs into a Seq for the type system (what Scala does internally).

```
action :  Seq[T] => R
```

Comment: Ty; this also works. It shares the issue with getting a single variable rather than individual ones in the using block (`usingva(new FileWriter(file), new FileWriter(file)) { fw => ... }`) where fw is now a Seq[T] and I'd ideally like to get something closer to `usingva(new FileWriter(file), new FileWriter(file)) { fw1, fw2 => ... }`